# C matrix "crop" function

Tags: c, matrix

I am given a matrix of elements of dimensions **Width**x**Height** which is allocated dynamically. I need to "crop" a part of this matrix defined by the rectangle formed by: (start_col, start_line) (end_col, end_line)

---

**Example:**

Given the matrix (3*3):

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

And the coords: (1, 1) (1, 1)

The resulting matrix is:

```
5
```

How would I do this?

---

My matrix consists of struct elements like this:

```
typedef struct Pixel{
   int R;
   int G;
   int B;
}Pixel;
```

And so I declared and allocated the matrix like this:

```
Pixel** img;

img = (Pixel**)malloc(height*sizeof(Pixel*));
for (int i = 0; i <= height-1; i++){
    img[i] = (Pixel*)malloc(width*sizeof(Pixel));
}

// ...
//code to populate matrix
```

Now how should I use realloc to keep just the small submatrix that I need?

Comment: Some effort is expected from your side.

Comment: I was thinking about using realloc in some way but I cant figure out how.. The malloc is made line by line and how would I use the realloc in cases such as this example? When I need to get rid just of certain elements from the line.

Comment: You can't really use `realloc()` because it only keeps the start of the data when you shrink, so you'll need to allocate a new matrix of the right size and copy the relevant part of the big matrix into the new one.  Then you have to sort out the return value and freeing the old matrix if appropriate.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the tip! :D

Answer (score 0):

You could allocate rows the same as columns (so they'll be just pointer's to pixels, not pixels itself) then you could:

- create "smaller" table and reference pixel's to new table (and maybe free unused once)
- moving them to start and reallocating the whole matrix
- set all pixels that are "not used" to NULL and everything that is not NULL is your cropped image.
- return the structure or pointer to start point of cropping ([x][y] of start pixel, or pointer to pixel). and width[how many pixels to the right]/height[how many pixels to the left] of cropping - this way you wouldn't have to change structure at all just work on cropped image.

Answer (score 0):

> Now how should I use realloc to keep just the small submatrix that I need?

At first, you can free the not-to-be-kept rows' data. Then, after you have moved the remaining rows' data and pointers to the start of their respective memory space, you can `realloc` the spaces, e. g.:

```
void crop(Pixel ***img, int start_col, int start_line,
                        int * end_col, int * end_line)
{
    Pixel **imp = *img;
    // free the memory space of the to-be-dropped row data
    for (int i = 0;     i < start_line; ++i) free(imp[i]);
    for (int i = * end_line; ++i < height; ) free(imp[i]);
    // move the to-be-kept row pointers to start at row 0
    *end_line -= start_line;    // resulting last row
    size_t col_size = (*end_line+1) * sizeof *imp;  // resulting pointers' size
    memmove(imp, imp+start_line, col_size);
    // move the to-be-kept column data to start at column 0
    *end_col -= start_col;      // resulting last column
    size_t row_size = (*end_col+1) * sizeof **imp;  // resulting row data size
    for (int i = 0; i <= * end_line; ++i)
        memmove(imp[i], imp[i]+start_col, row_size),
        imp[i] = realloc(imp[i], row_size); // trim the memory space of the row
    *img = realloc(imp, col_size);  // trim the memory space of the row pointers
}
```

You'd call this function like:

```
    int end_col = 1, end_line = 1;
    crop(&img, 1, 1, &end_col, &end_line),  // yields new matrix and new ends
    height = end_line+1, width = end_col+1; // important: set new dimensions
```